# Keep footer at the bottom (footer doesn't have to move with scroll)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give my page extra height with:

```
html {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

which does what I want but I've got problem with the footer. I want it at the bottom but
I don't necessarily want it to move with scroll. Meaning, user has to scroll down to see the footer.

This is what I've got:

html:

```
<footer class="footer">
   <p>...</p>
</footer>
```

css:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #00cca3;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

when I change `position` to `relative` the footer is in the middle of screen because it's being positioned relative to other elements. Not good.

How can I achieve a footer at the bottom of the screen without having it to move along with scroll ?

Comment: did you try `position:absolute`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:relative;` to body and `position:absolute;` to footer.

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #00cca3;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <p>...</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: On my end it works only when I select `fixed`. If I use `absolute` or `relative` it's in the middle of screen.

Comment: then there might be another element is taking the `relative` position, you have to check that that is the reason it is sitting in the middle. If there are any `relative` position above parent then you have to check. Property `position:absolute;` will for sure work, this property is made for these situations.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `position:fixed` and set the top and right the right position.it will not move anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid), with [`align-content:space-between`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content), here is a working snippet:

```css
html, body {height: 100%}

body {
  display: grid;
  align-content: space-between; 
  margin: 0;
}

footer {background: #CCC}
```

```html
<div>Content</div>
<footer class="footer">
   <p>This is footer!</p>
</footer>
```